# logstash not reading logtype field from beats

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have logstash filebeat and elasticsearch running on one node.

I'm trying to get logstash to identify logs labeled as "syslog" and dump them in an index named "syslog", but it appears to not see the label as they are all going into the "uncategorized" index (my catch all default index)

Here is my beats config

```
/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - /var/log/messages
      fields:
        type: syslog
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["localhost:9901"]
```

Here is my logstash config file

```
/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash_server_syslog.conf
input {
    beats {
        port => "9901"
    }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["10.0.0.167:9200", "10.0.0.168:9200"]
      index => "syslog"
    }
  } else {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["10.0.0.167:9200", "10.0.0.168:9200"]
      index => "uncategorized"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the output (with a stdout{} stanza) would confirm this, but I'm guessing that you missed this part of [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-general.html):

> By default, the fields that you specify [in the 'fields' config'] will be grouped under a
>   fields sub-dictionary in the output document. To store the custom
>   fields as top-level fields, set the fields_under_root option to true.

Answer (score 1):

To set a custom `type` field in Filebeat using the [`document_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.0/configuration-filebeat-options.html#_document_type) configuration option.

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    - paths:
        - /var/log/messages
      document_type: syslog
```

This will set the `@metadata.type` field for use with Logstash whereas a custom field will not.